# authtools in django problems with migrations

Tags: python, django, authentication

I am trying to use Authtools for custom users in django.

I am following documentation from their site:

[django-authtools.readthedocs](http://django-authtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#installation)

I started a new project, created admin.

Then I:

inserted `authtools` in `INSTALLED_APPS`.
inserted `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authtools.User'` in settings.py

in urls i did:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from authtools import urls

from django.contrib import admin
from authtools import urls 
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('authtools.urls')),]
```

Finally I ran python manage.py migrate

and i received following:

> django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory:
>   Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency
>   authtools.0001_initial on database 'default'.

I have no idea what is going on. Does anyone understand?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a fresh database? Changing `AUTH_USER_MODEL` for an existing project [is very difficult](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project).

Comment: It's completely fresh.

Comment: Did you run `migrate` before you installed `authtools`? If so, try dropping the database, recreating it, then running migrate again.

Comment: Thank, I droped database and started migrations, it seems it works. Thanks.

Comment: But, for someone upgrading for example his application. How would I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `authtools` to `INSTALLED_APPS` and set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authtools.User'` *before* you do the initial migration.

Since it's a new project, it should be straight forward to drop the database, recreate it, then run `migrate` again.